# W3C Throttles DTD/XSD requests; is there a mirror or file list?

Tags: performance, xsd, w3c, dtd, throttling

The W3C has started throttling requests to XSD/DTD files, adding as much as a minute of latency to the request:

http://www.w3.org/Help/Webmaster.html#slowdtd

I want to be able to mirror the standards specifications locally so that users don't have to wait for the server to respond. However I'm struggling to find a file list for the W3C standards.

Anyone know such as list or has some way to produce one, or knows of a W3C mirror site?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this actually matters? As the site you linked to says, merely viewing a page with a DTD won't result in the browser fetching the DBD

Comment: In order to make sense of an XML document, you need any associated DTD's, so most validating XML Parsers will try to load the DTD's. This can add literally minutes to the load time for a trivial document.

Answer (score 1):

The best answers to your questions are the ones in [the blog post](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/) linked from the URI you cite.

Options available to users of XML software (as opposed to developers) include:

- running a local caching proxy
- storing a local copy of the DTD files, making an OASIS XML Catalog for them, and using XML processors that support catalogs
- complaining vocally to the vendors of the commercial XML software you use, if they do not support catalogs
- helping modify any open source XML software you use to make it support catalogs

Answer (score 0):

Use the [OpenKomodo Github repo](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/contrib/catalogs/) to grab the most common DTDs, then reference the local copy rather than depending on a third party.